# Convertion from extended ascii to utf8

Tags: c++, utf-8, protocol-buffers, extended-ascii

How do you convert an std::string encoded in extended ascii to utf8 using microsoft visual studio 2005?

I'm using google protocol buffer and it's complaining about non utf8 characters in my string if I give it without conversion, which is true...

Comment: What do you mean by "extended ASCII"?

Comment: There is no such thing as "extended ASCII". You first need to find out the encoding (like ISO 8859-1 aka Latin-1 or some Windows codepage).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII I guess I'm talking about ISO-8859-1

Comment: Where did the string come from? You should define the boundaries where character conversion is taking place. Internally all strings should be a certain format (and it seems you need UTF-8) therefore any input to your code should also be UTF-8 (or converted by the input method automatically). So the question is where is the unsanitized string coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MultiByteToWideChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319072%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert your string to UTF-16, then use [WideCharToMultiByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374130%28VS.85%29.aspx) to convert it to UTF-8.

Comment: @Andrey: Last time I looked into the issue (which I freely admit to be long ago), I found no other way than the route via UTF-16.

Comment: ASCII chars with code > 127 are invalid in terms of UTF-8. and MultiByte stands for UTF-8. this will not work, i tell you, just try. may be you (or me :) ) misunderstood the question.

Comment: @Andrey: `MultiByteToWideChar()` can also convert system-encoded text to UTF-16. Is that the source of our misunderstanding? TTBOMK, this is all the Win32 API offers to convert between system encoding and UTF-8.

Comment: @Andrey, `MultiByteToWideChar` can convert from *many* code pages, not just UTF-8. That's what its first parameter indicates.

Comment: @sbi you are right, this will work if you pass 1252 as codepage, but still i like my method, it is faster :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume that mysterious Exntended ASCII is just Latin1. Then use mask from wikipedia:

> 110y yyxx  10xx xxxx

Since you have only 00..FF then you have: `1100 00xx  10xx xxxx`.

Conversion algorithm will be following, if char code is < 127 then just dump it as is, if it is > 127 then you do `0xC0 | ((x & 0xC0) >> 24)` goes to first byte, second is `((x & 0x3F) | 0x80)`

Comment: What "mask from Wikipedia" are you talking about? You have not generated valid UTF-8, either; UTF-8 does not have any zero bytes in it.